# Sitecore RTE Timeout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, session-timeout, rich-text-editor

We are facing the issue below with Sitecore RTE.

1. User logs on to Sitecore Desktop.
2. User opens the item with RTE field and start editing text on RTE.
3. User gets distracted, leaves the browser open.
4. User comes back after 2minute and tries to accept the changes.
5. The RTE shows the exception below:

   *"The Operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or server failure".*

I tried the solution on link below editing Editorpage.aspx

[Sitecore SDN link here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Avoid%20session%20timeouts%20in%20RTE.aspx)

I made sure that there is significant amount of timeout set on web.config as well as IIS app pool.

Has anyone faced this? If so, any solution will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue for Sitecore versions 6.5 up6 and later, with Analytics installed. There is a workaround here:

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0135940

It seems that Sitecore sometimes mistakenly identifies editors as robots and then reduces the timeout to save memory.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Sitecore:

When content authors use RTE for a long period of time and try to save their work by clicking Accept Changes, the following error occurrs:

"The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a timeout or a server failure. Please try again."

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Avoid%20session%20timeouts%20in%20RTE.aspx

---

The following message may occur when saving changes made in Rich Text fields after editing them for short periods of time, such as 3-5 minutes.
The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a timeout or a server failure. Please try again.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/135940

Answer (score 0):

This issue still seems to exist in Sitecore 9+. It happens when the user's session is detected as bot. Sitecore then sets a very short expiry time leading to this behaviour.

A simple workaround is to disable robots detection on CM instances:

```
<setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots">
    <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```